# Sequence contains no elements exception in Entity Framework

Tags: database, entity-framework, null

I get the following exception when I type the following EF command:

```
var license = outerContext.CompanyLicenses.First();
```

Error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Core.dll
>
> Additional information: Sequence contains no elements

The SQL query which the EF command is executing on the database is:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Data] AS [Data], 
    [Extent1].[LicenseFile] AS [LicenseFile], 
    [Extent1].[Validation] AS [Validation]
FROM 
    [dbo].[CompanyLicenses] AS [Extent1]
```

It's throwing me that exception because `outerContext.CompanyLicenses.First()` is returning null or empty but when I check in the database in the Management Studio the same SQL query returns an one row result.

What do you think the problem could be?

Comment: just guess, did you connect to the same database for EF and management studio?

Comment: Yes I did . The connection string is always the same.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the you're not connected to the right database

Comment: On a side note to avoid such exceptions you might want to use FirstOrDefault API instead of First as First API will always throw an exception the moment your table becomes empty.